# How Java deal with hard coded numeric values?

Tags: java, int

I have **decompiled** a Java class which contain this line :

```
DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23);
```

Until now i believe that Java consider that literal numeric value is `int`, So why they cast `23` ? And in general how Java deal with hard coded numeric values ?

Edit: Im not interested in this specific case, but interested to go deeper with Java in general.

Comment: Is this specifc line the result of the decompilation process or is this what source file contains?

Comment: a hardcoeded number either represents an `int` or a `double` if it is written as `.0` or `0.0`.

Comment: @Tunaki Godd question, this is a result of decompiled class, do you think that decompiler may give something different than source code ?

Comment: You could be fooled by the decompiler but anyway, the int cast in unnecessary

Comment: How is this a duplicate? OP is asking why a decompiler is emitting a cast; dupe is asking why a too-large integer causes a compiler error.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo No, OP is asking "And in general how Java deal with hard coded numeric values ?" which is answered over there but also in others posts. An integer literal is an `int`, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Oracle Java Tutorials Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int.

As for the particular decompiled statement:

```
DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23);
```

Only the person that coded the statement could answer for sure.  Perhaps he wasn't sure if the 23 was a byte or an int.

Answer (score 2):

I still believe it is related to the used decompiler.

It can be assumed that the signature of the method is `DatabaseError.throwSqlException(int i)`.

The statement `DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23)` would be compiled as `DatabaseError.throwSqlException(23)` - the literal is of type `int` and the method parameter type is of type `int`

the `DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23L)` would be compiled as `DatabaseError.throwSqlException(23)` - the value can be stored without precision lose in an `int` and the method parameter type is of type `int`

The byte code is in both cases

```
bipush 23    // push the value on the operand stack
invokestatic // DatabaseError.throwSqlException:(I)V
```

Decompiled it would be `DatabaseError.throwSqlException(23)`. Because in case it was `23L` in the source code, this information isn't in the bytecode.

A bytecode similar to `DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23)` could be

```
ldc2_w       // push a long from constant pool on the operand stack
l2i          // convert top value on the operand stack from long to int 
invokestatic // DatabaseError.throwSqlException:(I)V
```

But this is decompiled by `jad` and `jd-gui` to `DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23L)` (notice the `L` after the value).

**edit** The above bytecode is decompiled by `CFR` as `DatabaseError.throwSqlException((int)23)`. So it really depend on the used decompiler.

Comment: Thank you, you give so much informations, it's [CFR online decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/)

Comment: @54l3d Thanks. So it really depends on the used decompiler.